# Можно ли статично получить имя класса не зная имя самого класса?

Tags: java, классы

На данный момент я делаю так в каждом классе проекта:

```
public class A {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);
}
```

Чтобы избежать надобности каждый раз вводить новый класс при копировании этой декларации возможно ли сделать что-то такое: (?)

```
public class A {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
}
```

Такой вариант не будет работать, так как **`logger`** статичен и принадлежит классу:

```
public class A {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [Lombok Project](https://projectlombok.org/):

```
@Slf4j
public class A {
    // private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class); - считайте эта строка присутствует
}
```

И не нужно вообще ничего писать. Та же ситуация и с getters, setters, equals, hashCode, ...

Answer (score 3):

Такой вот хак есть

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getSimpleName());
```

Comment: Очень интересное решение. Спасибо. Но я вижу его минус. Создаеться новый объект. Это скорее всего замедлит код

Comment: @S.G. код выполняется один раз при инициализации класса (не объекта), так что "замедление" от создания одного объекта едва ли будет ощутимым; вот getEnclosingClass() в данном случае будет наверное наиболее "тяжелым".

Comment: @Ramiz но в проекте присутствуют 500 или более классов, как думаете это не замедлит код?